# Change the way of sliding div's and their event caller

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML part:

```
<div id="container">

    <div id="box1" class="box">Div #1</div>
    <div id="box2" class="box">Div #2</div>
    <div id="box3" class="box">Div #3</div>
    <div id="box4" class="box">Div #4</div>
    <div id="box5" class="box">Div #5</div>
    <div id="box6" class="box">Div #6</div>
    <div> <button class="Animate">left Animation</button></div>
    <div> <button class="Animate2">right Animation</button></div>

</div>
```

​

Javascript part:

```
$('.box').click(function() {

    $(this).animate({
        left: '-50%'
    }, 500, function() {
        $(this).css('left', '150%');
        $(this).appendTo('#container');
    });

    $(this).next().animate({
        left: '50%'
    }, 500);
});​
```

CSS part:

```
body {
    padding: 0px;    
}

#container {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;  
}

.box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 300px;
    line-height: 300px;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid black;
    left: 150%;
    top: 100px;
    margin-left: -25%;
}

#box1 {
    background-color: green;
    left: 50%;
}

#box2 {
    background-color: yellow;
}

#box3 {
    background-color: red;
}

#box4 {
    background-color: orange;
}

#box5 {
    background-color: blue;
}
#box6 {
    background-color: grey;
}​
```

When the above code is complied and "**div's in the pages are clicked**" they move towards their left. I want the divs to move to their left when left animation button is clicked in sequence 1-2-3-4-5-1 and move to their right when right animation button is clicked in sequence 1-5-4-3-2-1. I have already posted a similar question on this forum but I accepted the answers by mistake even though they were not exactly what I was looking for. My mistake I was not clear enough in my question. I am sorry if am asking for a big code here. All the help is appreciated. This is the link to http://jsfiddle.net/ykbgT/4151/ 
This is the desired functionality: http://basic-slider.com/ not so good looking though!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/tppiotrowski/VLzN4/1/

I used your existing CSS and HTML and only modified the Javascript. I think your question implied that you did not want the original functionality of clicking on the div, but instead wanted to use the two buttons. Please comment if you want me to re-add in the clicking on the div functionality of advancing the slides.

```
$(function() {
    function createSlider(el_left, el_right, items) {
        var index = 0;
        el_left.click(function() {
            var $this = items.eq(index);
            $this.animate({
                left: '-50%'
            }, 500);
            index = (index + 1) % items.length;
            var $next = items.eq(index);
            $next.css('left', '150%');
            $next.animate({
                left: '50%'
            }, 500);
        });
        el_right.click(function() {
            var $this = items.eq(index);
            $this.animate({
                left: '150%'
            }, 500);
            index = (index - 1) % items.length;
            var $next = items.eq(index);
            $next.css('left', '-50%');
            $next.animate({
                left: '50%'
            }, 500);
        });
    }

    createSlider($('.Animate'), $('.Animate2'), $('.box'));​
});
```

This function takes three jquery objects as arguments. The first is the button you wish to advance to the left. The second is the button you wish to advance to the right. The third is the items you wish to slide.

Comment: You understood exactly what the functionality is desired but when I open the jsfiddle link that you posted its not working at all. But thanks for the effort.

Comment: Oh you edited the post. I am so sorry. It is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a ton. :-)

Comment: You made the code so dynamic that I can add as many divs as I want. More than what I wanted from the code. Super solution. Thanks.

Comment: I dont know why the code is not working on my local machine.. :-(

Comment: Is there some kind of resource or javascript I need to put in. or some other command I need to write to load the javascript?

Comment: @kapilchhattani did you load jQuery library? You need to include `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` in your HTML file.

Comment: I updated the code to wrap it inside a jquery ready function `$(function() { ... }`. This will make sure the code doesn't start executing until all the content is loaded.

Comment: I tried this also but its not working, but when I wrote the script inside the body tags then it started working, Why isn't the code that you posted working then? Even the above function gets called after the complete HTML loading right?

Comment: I just had to take out two ";" from the posted code. I dont know why but neways its working now. Thanks again. :-)